# How to expose MySQL database in kubernetes using Kong Gateway?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

I installed kong using helm chart. In `values.yaml` I specified two TCP ports in Stream section:

```
stream:
- containerPort: 39019 #MongoDB
  servicePort: 39019
  protocol: TCP
  parameters:
    - ssl

- containerPort: 43576 #MySQL
  servicePort: 43576
  protocol: TCP
  parameters:
    - ssl
```

My intention is to expose one port for MongoDB and another for MySQL.
After that, I created a TCPIngress file for both databases:

one for MySQL

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1beta1
kind: TCPIngress
metadata:
  name: tcp-mysql
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
    konghq.com/plugins: global-file-log
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - s.mytest.domain
    secretName: s.mytest.domain-certificate
  rules:
    - host: s.mytest.domain
      port: 43576 
      backend:
        serviceName: mysql
        servicePort: 3306
```

and other for MongoDB

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1beta1
kind: TCPIngress
metadata:
  name: tcp-mongodb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
    konghq.com/plugins: global-file-log
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - s.mytest.domain
    secretName: s.mytest.domain-certificate
  rules:
    - host: s.mytest.domain
      port: 39019 
      backend:
        serviceName: mongodb
        servicePort: 27017
```

with this configuration, MongoDB works perfect, but MySQL doesnt.
I couldn't find a way to connect to MySQL using my test domain.
If I do a port-forward to my MySQL pod, it works as expected.

I'm new to Kong and Kubernetes in general. How can I trace whats going wrong and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, resolved by exposing TCP ports as in https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/3.0.x/guides/services/tcp/#expose-additional-ports

It's clearly explained in the document that by default the proxy listens only for HTTP / HTTPS protocols. For other protocolos like UDP / TCP, we need to explicitly instruct kong proxy to do so. Steps extracted from the fore-mentioned document are as below:

> Make sure to change the port you are planning to expose.

1. Update the deployment

```
 kubectl patch deploy -n kong kong-gateway --patch '{
   "spec": {
     "template": {
       "spec": {
         "containers": [
           {
             "name": "proxy",
             "env": [
               {
                 "name": "KONG_STREAM_LISTEN",
                 "value": "0.0.0.0:9000, 0.0.0.0:9443 ssl"
               }
             ],
             "ports": [
               {
                 "containerPort": 9000,
                 "name": "stream9000",
                 "protocol": "TCP"
               },
               {
                 "containerPort": 9443,
                 "name": "stream9443",
                 "protocol": "TCP"
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
 }'
```

2. Update the proxy

```
kubectl patch service -n kong kong-gateway-proxy --patch '{
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "stream9000",
        "port": 9000,
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "targetPort": 9000
      },
      {
        "name": "stream9443",
        "port": 9443,
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "targetPort": 9443
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

3. Finally, write the Ingress

```
echo "apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1beta1
kind: TCPIngress
metadata:
  name: echo-plaintext
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
spec:
  rules:
  - port: 9000
    backend:
      serviceName: echo
      servicePort: 1025
" | kubectl apply -f -
```

> Suggestion: DB's are never meant to be accessible via internet, for development requirements you can port forward the service and get connected for development and maintenance works.

```
kubectl port-forward svc/service-mysql 3306:3306
```

Comment: Please explain **how to check if the TCP ports are exposed**. If the link become unavailable in the future your answer will be useless.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @mozway, explained a bit more.